# UITextField.attributedPlaceholder NSForegroundColorAttributeName global value where?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I can easily retrieve the UITextField.attributedPlaceholder NSForegroundColorAttributeName value of a UITextField object, but where does the UITextField ultimately get this value from? Is there some global setting somewhere? The value can't be hard-coded. Where can I get my hands on this value?

Comment: Are you wondering where the default value is set? Why don't you think it's hardcoded into `UITextField`?

Comment: Do you want to change UITextField.attributedPlaceholder's NSForegroundColorAttributeName value?

Comment: rmaddy - I guess I don't really, but that would be terrible programming practice.

Comment: shuvo - ultimately, yes, but I know how to do that. I want to use the value to make consistent other controls I want to create placeholder text for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found here: [attributedplaceholder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619610-attributedplaceholder)

> This property is nil by default. If set, **the placeholder string is
>   drawn using a 70% gray color** and the remaining style information
>   (except the text color) of the attributed string. Assigning a new
>   value to this property also replaces the value of the placeholder
>   property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting
>   information. Assigning a new value to this property does not affect
>   any other style-related properties of the text field.

Comment: In other words, it's hardcoded into `UITextField`, correct?

Comment: No, I'm simply pointing it out due to your reply to my original comment prior to you posting this answer. You didn't seem to think it was hard coded but this answer indicates that it is. Just summarizing. BTW - when you reply to som one, be sure to precede their user id with an @.

Comment: @rmaddy - my apologies then, I'm sorry.